# node.js rename the files incrementally

Tags: node.js, filesystems

I have been using Node.JS file system module for performing various file related operations. I have a need to verify the file name if exists in a directory and if exists i would need to keep a suffix at the end of the file. Typically how windows does with duplicate file names..

if TestFile.txt already exists and another file with same names comes in during processing the new file should be renamed as TestFile (1).txt and next file with same name should be renamed as TestFile (2).txt.

What could be the best way to achieve this. Do i have to use a temporary array to keep all file names and traverse through for each? This is a multi threaded environment and there could be 50,000+ documents coming for processing.

Thanks a ton.

Comment: The straight-forward solution on ANY language is to check direct file existense, and if so, check next variant (file (1).txt). Sure, hashtable of names will give speed boost in case you need rename many files. In case of parallel tasks you can do two things: 1) assign only one thread on one folder, so thread will not race each other and you don't get name conflicts; 2) Use hashtable of names; in this approach you will need lock/atomic operations mechanism on hashtable; I don't add this as answer because I'm unfamiliar with node.js and maybe there is better approach in this particular case.

Comment: @Tommi Node.js is single threaded, so as long as there aren't multiple instances running, there shouldn't be a problem with a race condition. I think whether to use a hashtable or direct FS lookup depends on whether the lookup creates a bottleneck. If you're writing non-stop as fast as you can, use a hashtable for speed. If files come in one at a time in a spread out fashion, then FS lookup might be preferable for its lower memory usage.